# JBAS010153: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique

Tags: jboss7.x, cluster-computing, jboss-eap-6

I am getting the following WARN message while I start my host which is one of the Host Controller (HC) that is attached to the Domain Controller(DC).

> [Server:server-two] 14:06:13,822 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) JBAS010153: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique.

And my host-slave.xml has the following config...

```
        <server-identities>
             <!-- Replace this with either a base64 password of your own, or use a vault with a vault expression -->
             <secret value="c2xhdmVfdXNlcl9wYXNzd29yZA=="/>
        </server-identities>
```

I hope this config is the reason...... maybe I didn't understand..... but I couldn't find `node identifier property` rather this is the default secret value which I hope could be the cause of this WARN message.

However, I didn't mention HC to lookup `host-slave.xml`..... the command which I ran to start my HC is.....

`[host-~-\-\-\bin]$./domain.sh -Djboss.domain.master.address=nnn.nn.nn.88 -b nnn.nn.nn.89 -bmanagement nnn.nn.nn.89 &`

nnn.nn.nn.88 is my DC

Else please advise what's cause of the WARN message.

And please let me know the implication of this WARN message and advise us on the required config to overcome and sort out any consecutive consequences that would've been bound for this WARN.

Comment: In JBoss EAP 7 the same warning appears with a different ID: WFLYTX0013 instead of JBAS010153.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm new to wildfly, and noticed this warning when I started it standalone from eclipse (I'm doing the following tutorial: https://wwu-pi.github.io/tutorials/lectures/eai/020_tutorial_jboss_project.html)

The fix was to add a node-identifier to the core-environment in the subsystem:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:2.0">
        <core-environment node-identifier="meindertwillemhoving">
            <process-id>
                <uuid/>
            </process-id>
        </core-environment>
        <recovery-environment socket-binding="txn-recovery-environment" status-socket-binding="txn-status-manager"/>
</subsystem>
```

This is in file [wildfly]\standalone\configuration\standalone.xml. 
This is the same answer as https://developer.jboss.org/message/880136#880136

Comment: The answer is correct. I just want to add that the CLI command for setting the node identifier is `/subsystem=transactions:write-attribute(name=node-identifier,value=someuniquevalue)`. And I am using Red Hat JBoss EAP 7, where the error code is `WFLYTX0013` (everything else seems to be identical).

Comment: is meindertwillemhoving mean something or any unique name

Answer (score 2):

According to [WFLY-10541](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-10541) if you are using WildFly v14.0.0 or newer you can pass the following to the startup script to set the transaction node identifier:

```
-Djboss.tx.node.id=<some-unique-id>
```

Comment: Thanks! _for_ the `java property` - probably the specific one, but, however,- very specific one,- is that the Spec. is clear **WFLY-10541**. Maybe I am sustaining the Question! as other irrelevance popped in my Technicality! Apologize.

Comment: @DevAnandSadasivam I just thought I drop this here for anyone who ends up with the similar issue and visits this page. It might help them :) I am not after upvotes or accepted answer :D

Comment: I used this to get rid of the warning. But then the logging stopped. I'm running Wildfly 25.0.1 version. When I remove the property, the logging starts again.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the node identifier to an unique value is only required for proper handling of XA Transactions.
You can set it as follows in your XML configuration:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:6.0">
    <core-environment node-identifier="${jboss.tx.node.id}">
```

It needs to be a unique value up to 23 bytes long.
More about this here: http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-configuration/configuring-transactions-jta-using-jboss-as7-wildfly

Answer (score 0):

For this `<server-identities>` is not the issue. In fact, it shouldn't be touched at all.

When JBoss is started in domain mode by `domain.sh`, by default there will be three servers `server-one` `server-two` `server-three`. When you are running one more HC attached to the DC.... the defaulted server which is in auto-start mode will get clash when we start HC attaching to DC,- by the following command.

`[host-~-\-\-\bin]$./domain.sh -Djboss.domain.master.address=nnn.nn.nn.88 -b nnn.nn.nn.89 -bmanagement nnn.nn.nn.89 &`

Or by having the host configuration at HC (default `host.xml`... until unless we choose a different one....).

```
<domain-controller>
      <remote host="${jboss.domain.master.address:nnn.nn.nn.88}" port="${jboss.domain.master.port:9999}" security-realm="ManagementRealm"/>
<domain-controller>
```

In order to solve this, we need to turn `auto-start` to `false`..... And we need to create a new `server-group`...... To that group we need to add `dc-created-server` and `hc-created-server`..... we can choose the appropriate same profile either `full-ha` or `full` for both created servers across DC and HC.

SO when we start the group by configuring the required `HEAP` size including `permgen space`... You could start both DC and HC.... and in DC you could see both of your-created-servers are started in the created `server-group`.

> DC- Domain Controller
> HC- Host Controller

To deploy you need to upload `.ear` or `web-archive` in the Application Console. You cannot place it in the `deployments` folder as how you do in standalone mode with `.dodeploy` file.

If you upload the same `.ear` next version do the `Replace` option instead of the `Remove & Add` option in the upload process.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @kaptan's answer I added the following to the bottom of
**bin/standalone.conf**:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.tx.node.id=`hostname -f`
```

This way I don't have to remember to add the "-Djboss.tx.node.id=" when running up wildfly by hand.